# Integration of RASA with Twilio

Tags: python, flask, sms, twilio-api, rasa-core

I’m trying to integrate RASA with Twilio but I’m getting an error with the `HttpInputChannel` in the following statement in `run_twilio.py`:

`agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5500,’/’, input_channel))`

Following is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hCYC.png).

But it (`HttpInputChannel`) works fine when I integrate it with slack. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to upgrade to Rasa 1.x which comes with a lot of bug fixes and new features. Also you can use a file `credentials.yml` to connect your bot to Twilio.
As described [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/twilio/) you only have to add something like this to the file `credentials.yml`:

```
twilio:
  account_sid: "ACbc2dxxxxxxxxxxxx19d54bdcd6e41186"
  auth_token: "e231c197493a7122d475b4xxxxxxxxxx"
  twilio_number: "+440123456789"
```

and then run the bot with `rasa run` (Rasa 1.0 also comes with new command line interface). 
Maybe the community in the Rasa forum can also help you (https://forum.rasa.com).